# Why is arguments.length not changing even after appending new value to the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arguments

```js
function test(num0, num1) {
  console.log(arguments.length); // output: 1
  arguments[1] = 20;
  console.log(arguments.length); // output: 1
}

test(8);
```

But when the same action is performed on a normal array then the length of array is changing-

```js
var arr = [2];
console.log(arr.length); // output: 1
arr[1] = 5;
console.log(arr.length); // output: 2
```

So why is the length of arguments[] array not changing after assigning value to new index?

Comment: `arguments` is an array-*like* object. Think more `{length: 1, 0: 8}` than `[8]`.

Comment: `arguments` is not an array, but array like. anything which applies to an array does not apply to `arguments`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so if I convert this object to an array then index 0 of that array should be storing the value of length?

Comment: No; if you convert it to an array the value at the 0th index will be the first argument, 8.

Comment: @NinaScholz but arguments.length is returning a value which works for array but not for objects.

Comment: it is an object with a nonwritable property.

Comment: @jonrsharpe according to your explanation if I were to apply _Object.keys(arguments)_ then it should return _length_ and _0_ but its not

Comment: I didn't say that's exactly what it was, I said that's what you could _think of_. Read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Read and understood. Thanks for reference. Is there any way to get the source code of arguments object?

Comment: There isn't a single implementation, you'll have to pick an open-source engine (e.g. [V8](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git)) and look for that object.

Answer (score -1):

Argument is not an array but an array-like object, it does not have the [] operator for assigning values (only for reading) like we have in array's. One solution is to convert you argument to and array and then proceed with the new object.

```js
function test(num0, num1) {
  var arg = Array.from(arguments);
  console.log(arg.length); // output: 1
  arg[1] = 20;
  console.log(arg.length); // output: 2
}

test(8);
```

Comment: Does this arguments object store its length as a data element like _arguments = {length: 1, 0:8}_

Comment: The `arguments` object *does* "have the [] operator"; as the question shows you can assign by index `arguments[1] = 20`. You can also get the values by index e.g. `console.log(arguments[0])`. It just doesn't update the length property when you assign beyond the last index like an array does, because it's not an array.

Comment: Hey @PracticalMinds, it does not have the length field in the same manner, in the example above "length" is Array Property.